# Avalonia UI. Как получить размер рабочего стола (без панели задач)?

Tags: c#, ui, avalonia

Может ли кто-нибудь поделится примером кода, с помощью которого можно получить размеры рабочего стола (без панели задач)?
Через WinForms понятно как получить:
 `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea`

А вот как реализовать подобное через Avalonia UI?

Comment: Попробуйте `SystemParameters.WorkArea`

Comment: К сожалению, похоже, этот класс доступен только под Windows (VS Code в linux на него ругается), а мне нужна кроссплатформенность, потому был выбран Avalonia UI. Иначе не было бы проблем реализации через WinForms.

Comment: Ну на крайний случай что то типа [такого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20164262/c-sharp-and-ubuntu-how-do-i-get-size-of-primary-screen)

Comment: vitidev, спасибо, это конечно костыльный вариант, но как временное решение сойдет. Правда там пример получения разрешения экрана, а не рабочей области. Но сам подход к решению интересный.

Comment: Ну это лучше решений "распахни окно на весь экран и вычитай размер"

Comment: Но хуже например такого "var height = Screens.Primary.WorkingArea.Height", как в некоторых найденных мной примерах в интернете. Но беда в том, что сейчас этот код не работает ибо требует конструктора "Screens(IScreenImpl)". Потому и мной был задан вопрос с просьбой примера, как правильно это сейчас реализовать. Документация на авалонию очень скудная и примеров тоже не хватает.

Comment: Для пояснения, задача была определить размеры рабочего стола и сместить окно в правый нижний угол при его открытии при запуске приложения. Со смещением тоже не очень понятно, но тут я не сильно еще вникал.